# Grails- RESTful web services with pdf attachments?

Tags: grails, restful-architecture, groovyws

I've to implements Grails RESTful Web Services for both consumer and provider.
Provider has to return pdf document and consumer has to process it and save it to the db.
As a provider how to return pdf document using grails rest services. 
I used MTOM in soap web services to achieve this but not sure how to implement in Grails rest services.

Please suggest me how to achieve this with some example code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what I did and this is what you can do for the producer

```
>  def boas = callservicetogenerateReport // this should return an
> byteArray
>         // setting the content type
>         response.setContentType("application/pdf");
>         response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=sample.pdf")
>         response.setContentLength(boas.size());
>         // write ByteArrayOutputStream to the ServletOutputStream
>         response.outputStream << boas.toByteArray()
>         response.outputStream.flush()
>         response.outputStream.close()
```

For Consumer this is what i did in a rest call which actually handles a user submitting a file via post.

```
request.multiFileMap."files[]".each {file ->
                def newFile = new Expando(name: file.originalFilename, size: file.size)
                callServicetoAddFileToDB(file)
  }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: About the consumer - As a consumer I've to send request data and need to get the PDF from provider..@Producer: Do you think I've to write it to response, instead can I get PDF in  byyearray as a response, isn't it?

Comment: From consumer, are you posting a file to the provider?

Comment: Question- How is a user going to select a file to be sent ?

Comment: User(Consumer) don't select any file, provider has to return a pdf generated file  based on the request criteria received  from consumer. Once consumer receives the file, he will store it into DB.

Comment: IS this something which a user is going to select or is this something which is being generated by a seperate service ?

Comment: Yes...consumer is one grails application and provider is another grails application.. Upon clicking a button 'generateReport' in consumer application, there will be a rest call to another grails application which will generate the pdf and return to the consumer.

Comment: So if that's the case just follow what I did for the producer. Where I say callServiceTogenerateReport(). this will be a http call to your your application which will just write it the data to the response stream. Your code would actually then pick the file from the outputstream and again write it back to the responsestream of the consumer application.  Here is an example how you would do it http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/index.html

Comment: In case `client` wants the `pdf` file downloadable then the same can be rendered using "Grails Render Plugin".